# How to react to native event in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, event-handling

I am rendering html using `v-html` in which I am binding to a click event like so:

```
<template>
  <q-page fill-height>
    <div>
      <q-btn flat @click="drawer = !drawer" round dense icon="menu" />
      <span v-html="html"></span>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
  ...
  data: {
     return {
       id: null
     }
  },
  mounted() {
     this.$el.children[0].children[1].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(event.target.id)
    });
  }
</script>
```

This prints `event.target.id` to the console as expected. It seems that the value of `event.target.id` can not be set to a reactive property.

How can I set the value of `event.target.id` equal to a different reactive data property so I can handle changes properly?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with `event.target.id`? Also, you shouldn't need to add a native click handler here. `@click.prevent="handleClick($event)"` would work too (where `handleClick` is a custom method)

Comment: oh! didn't realize I could do it directly on the span element. this worked. if you want to put it in an answer i will mark it as such. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copied from my comment above]

You shouldn't need to add a native click handler here. `@click.prevent="handleClick($event)"` would work too (where `handleClick` is a custom method).